# Adding script tag in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try if it possible to respect the "Separation of concerns" while programming in javascript and html. In many situations, I have to execute some code after the page is loaded and I use the document ready function of jQuery to do that. I prefer to put my javascript code in a separated file. The problem is that I have a script file that I use to a couple of html files and the document ready function should not be executed in all of these pages. For this reason, I put a script tag directly in my html and the document ready function in this tag but the rest of the javascript code is in my javascript file.

Is it a good practice to put the document ready function in the html to promote reusing the script file in different contexts or is there any good practices to achieve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML put something like:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="common_stuff.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="stuff_for_this_page.js"></script>
```

Then use the Apache [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) module to send the output to the client.

This will have the advantage of separating the Javascript from the HTML in development but not requiring the client to wait for the JQuery `ready` function to be loaded separately.

Comment: Thank you @Ed Heal, it seem to be a good solution but is it not an overhead to have a js file just to put the document ready function?

Comment: @ChristopherDalman - The `stuff_for_this_page.js` may contain other stuff as well. Besides the `ready` function could be complex. Also when editing the `common_stuff.js` you know that will have a larger impact (thus require more testing!)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Angularjs](http://angularjs.org/) or [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/). Both these can be used to implement a structure and design to you javascripts.